# AWS Step Function pass output of nth state to another without passing to interim states?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-step-functions

I have an AWS step function that executes several ETL tasks that are combinations of lambda, glue jobs etc. Here, for these states I want pass an unique ID called flow_id that can be flown to every state and I can record the states progress in data base. Here for some steps like glue jobs and athena query they cannot give me back flow_id as ouput.

So can I pass the output of the first_state (say generated a flow_id) to third step without actually passing it to second step.

Comment: Minimal code example?